# Waypoint sequencing API returning server error and no guidance on what the error is

Tags: rest, here-api

I am trying to run the waypoint sequencing request in this guide:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/example-truck.html

**This is the postman request I am issuing(Yes, I inserted my API key)**

```
https://wps.hereapi.com/v8/findsequence2?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}
&start=WiesbadenCentralStation;50.0715,8.2434
&destination1=FranfurtCentralStation;50.1073,8.6647
&destination2=DarmstadtCentralStation;49.8728,8.6326
&destination3=FrankfurtAirport;50.0505,8.5698
&destination4=HanauCentralStation;50.1218,8.9298
&end=MainzCentralStation;50.0021,8.259
&departure=2014-12-09T09:30:00%2b01:00
&mode=car;traffic:disabled;
```

All I get is: Status: 500 Internal Server Error.

**QUESTION 2:**
If we have to specify 100 waypoints will we run into any issues?

Comment: 100 waypoints should may be about the limit to what you can query through GET parameters. I.e. the URL will get too long after a certain number of characters

Comment: Hi JohnGa, could you please try your request again. We don't really see the 500 now. maybe there's an issue at that time.
For your question 2: The maximum number of waypoints including the start point and destination is 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic. If the routing mode pedestrian is used, the distance between each two of the waypoints must not be greater than 5km. You can refer to this doc: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

Answer (score 0):

For the issue related to 500 error, we don't see any  issue at our end.

For your question 2: The maximum number of waypoints including the start point and destination is 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic. If the routing mode pedestrian is used, the distance between each two of the waypoints must not be greater than 5km. You can refer to this doc:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html